# Get character position in StringBuilder when using contains

Tags: c#, .net

Been looking high and low but couldn't find how to do it.

I'd like to do the following

I'm trying to get the second element from converted ToString returnCode 
for example: A1235 is returnCode. 
I'm trying to get the "1"

edit: Guys. It can contain two "1"s but not on the second position of the string. I need an if statement that does xyz IF the second character of returnCode is 1. Don't think "Char" is going to work.

```
StringBuilder matchCode = new StringBuilder();
//returnCode is a stringbuilder type variable. 

if (returnCode.ToString().charAt(1).Contains("0"))
{
    matchCode.AppendLine("Match Confidence Level: 0 (Low Confidence)");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? You mention that you want to find a character position but your code checks if a string startswith a specific character(ignoring the fact that a char cannot contain another char).

Comment: `if (returnCode[0] == '0') ..`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Wouldn't it be `charAt(0)` if it was 'starts with'... I know it's not a real function, but I think the Java version is 0-based (I think)

Comment: @musefan: i'm fairly sure that OP thinks the first char is `text[1]`. However, isn't really important if it's the first or second char.

Comment: I'm trying to get the second element from converted ToString returnCode 
for example: A1235 is returnCode. 
returnCode.ToString().charAt(1) should be 1 (I think, since 0 is the start). 
It's simply an if case if the second character of my converted substring is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to cast your StringBuilder to string and then look for a char in it. You can use a code like this:

```
if (returnCode != null && returnCode.Length > 1 && returnCode[1] == '0') // no need to check for null if you are sure it's not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
returnCode.ToString().ElementAt(1) == '0'
```

If you want to compare with a character at a specific index within the produced string.

or

```
returnCode.Char[1] == '0'
```

If you don't need to build the final string.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but this code generates a string first, then checks for a character's value. There's no need to do that though, as StringBuilder already [exposes the Chars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.chars(v=vs.110).aspx_) property. You can write `returnCode.Chars[0] == '0';`

Comment: oh, yes, you are absolutely right. I just assumed the OP would have used `ToString()` anyways since they have used it themselves in their code, but I'll definitely add that one to the answer, for the sake of completeness